# Add contacts to outlook using Outlook Addin

Tags: outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook addin that syncs my application(abc) contacts with my outlook contacts. I am unable to do it using javascript.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your code and tell us what is wrong. As it stands now, there is nothing we could help you with

Comment: That is correct. JS addins are only running in response to user events. There is no way to have JS  code running continuously or in a secondary thread. You will need a COM addin for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use EWS or [Outlook REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) from your web-based add-ins. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Note, Mail Apps are run in the context of a particular Outlook item. That's why I'd recommend developing a COM add-in instead. It can be run with Outlook and handle a lot of actions that users do to keep in sync with your application all contacts. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started quickly.